# Transactions in LexDb

Tags: transactions, win-universal-app

Im using LexDb for Win8.1 universal App, I have to insert data in more than one table.
I want to use save / insert statement in one transaction for data consistency, So it should save all data or save nothing in case of exception or failure. I didn't  find a way to apply transaction in Lex Db.
sume forums say db.BulkWrite() creates transaction but its not creating transaction in true sense. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: (http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/12/09/Using-LexDB-as-a-local-storage-in-a-Windows-8-Store-app.aspx), transactions are not supported yet in LexDb.